# how to add another view by expanding the Grid View Rows in android

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-calendar

I have a `GridView`, with 3 elements per row, and when I click on an item, a new view comes below the row. It's a bit like a folder application on `iOS`. I didn't find any answer on SO or on Google. Maybe you can give me some hints. (Like `ExpandableListview` in android).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue some days ago in the work. I used to see someone have done same thing on iOS by putting a cover layer upon the grid view, which is a snapshot image of current grid view. Then split the snapshot image into two parts, add a new sub grid view into the middle of the cover layer. By doing this can create the experience of "expand" the grid view. At the same time, add click handler to the cover image which will remove the cover layer when the cover layer is clicked.

And I have created an [ExpandableGridView](https://github.com/thewaychung/ExpandableGridView) on GitHub, hope this can help those who need similar functionality.